# Inline nginx conf in composer.yml file: possible?

Tags: azure, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

I want to setup a reverse proxy with authentication for my webapp, here's my composer file:

```
 version: '3'
 services:
 nginx:
image: registry.azurecr.io/nginx:latest
container_name: nginx
volumes:
  - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  - ./nginx/.htpasswd:/etc/nginx/.htpasswd
ports:
  - 80:80

myapp:
image: registry.azurecr.io/myapp:latest
container_name: myapp
expose:
  - 8080
```

As you can see I rely on two files to edit the nginx configuration. Problem is that I want to deploy this application to azure's app services but azure does not allow to specify external configurations (as far as I know).

So, is there a way to specify a couple of username/passwords in this same composer file?

Comment: Any update for the question?

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you can use the persist storage for the web app or use the path mapping, then put the file in it. If you just want to put the file in the compose file, it seems it's impossible.

For persist storage, mount the persist volume to the path inside the container in the compose file, then enable the persist storage through setting the `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` as `true` in the app settings. For more details, see [Use persistent storage in Docker Compose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container#use-persistent-storage-in-docker-compose).

For path mapping, you need to create a storage account. Use the blob or the file share. See the document [containerized app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service%2Fcontainers%2Ftoc.json#containerized-apps). Set the volume like this:

```
wordpress:
  image: wordpress:latest
  volumes:
  - <custom-id>:<path_in_container>
```

For more details about steps, see [Serve content from Azure Storage in App Service on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-serve-content-from-azure-storage).

Comment: Problem is that it is on azure, not on my pc: I don't have a file system to store the volume in. For now I created a custom image containing an already set-up configuration but I don't like that too much. According to you is it possible to inject the configuration via environments variables? I would set up a proxypass with that and then inject the variable via docker compose

Comment: @Phate The persistent storage is set by Azure and you can see it in the kudu of the web app. You do not have the file system. And the environment variable is set in the appsetting, not in the compose file. The environment variables set in the compose file just can be used inside the container.